# how to integrate junit in gwt project with the ant build file

Tags: gwt, ant

I have a gwt project, and i want to do the unit test in my project, so i add a target of junit in the ant build file. But the build always fails,

**BUILD FAILED C:\SG\workspace\app\build.xml:78: The  for  must include junit.jar if not in Ant's own classpath**

here is the scripts

```
<target name="test" depends="clean.test,gwtc" description="run all Junit tests">
    <mkdir dir ="test/test"/>
    **<junit fork = "false" printsummary = "yes"/>** <!-- the line 78-->
    <classpath refid = "project.class.path"/>
    <batchtest todir = "test/test">
        <fileset dir = "test" includes="**/${test}Test.java"/>
    </batchtest>
    <formatter type = "xml"/>
    <junitreport toDir = "test/test">
        <fileset dir = "test/test"/>
        <report format="frames" todir="test"/>
    </junitreport>
    <exec os="window" executable="cmd.exe">
        <arg line="-a /Applications/Safari.app test/index.html"/>
    </exec>
 </target>
```

Comment: You forgot to add the scripts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You closed the `<junit />` tag too early.

This is correct. `classpath`, `batchtest` and `formatter` have to be inside the `junit` Tag:

```
<junit fork = "false" printsummary = "yes">
    <classpath refid = "project.class.path"/>
    <batchtest todir = "test/test">
        <fileset dir = "test" includes="**/${test}Test.java"/>
    </batchtest>
    <formatter type = "xml"/>
</junit>
```

And you have to make sure that `junit.jar` is either in ANT_HOME/lib,  referenced in project.class.path or added as another classpath like `<classpath refid = "junit.class.path"/>`.

Comment: Yes, I found these too, thank you very much. Besides, I added the ant-junit.jar. Then The problème is resolved.

Comment: I am sorry, i find that i don't have enough reputation to vote for your answer at the moment.